# How to control the execution based on logical input parameter in a method in Java

Tags: java

I have below method where based on the step passed I need to decide where to return from. Is there a way to implement the same without having to write the if statements? (Fine with redesigning the method)

(With Switch-Case I can do the reverse of it i.e. execute specified step and all others after it, for e.g. if step=3 then execute 3,4,5 and so on)

```
public void process(Document document, int step) {
    this.processHeader(document);
    
    if(step==1) {
      return;
    }

    this.processContent(document);
    
    if(step==2) {
      return;
    }

    this.processFooter(document);
    
    if(step==3) {
      return;
    }

    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Does it mean for step 3 you want to execute all processHeader, processContent and processFooter? Not only processFooter

Comment: @gdomo - Yes that's rights

Comment: *What could be cleaner, readable and easily maintainable way to do this?* will, most likely, give you an opinion-based answer. If there is anything specific you're not happy about, please be more specific in your question as well. Otherwise, "how can this be better" is very broad.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri thanks, tried to be more specific now.

Comment: Looks like programming antipattern. What's the reason to pass `int step` into the method?

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way is do what you do, but use `<=` to invoke only methods you need depending on the given `step`.

```java
public void process(Document document, int step) {
    if (step <= 0)
        this.processHeader(document);
    if (step <= 1)
        this.processContent(document);
    if (step <= 2)
        this.processFooter(document);
    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more involved solution would be to redesign your application using the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) for each process and an array or list of commands to be executed. It may be overkill for a low number of commands but it scale better and be more generic and dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

How much refactoring can you do?  Adding on to Oleg's answer, another approach would be to move the `if` to the step method so the `process` method body becomes fluent. Also change `step` type to an enum, along with some name changes to clarify intent.

```
enum DocumentProcessStep {
   PROCESS_HEADER,
   PROCESS_CONTENT,
   PROCESS_FOOTER,
}

class DocumentProcesser {

    public void process(Document doucment, DocumentProcessStep startWith) {
        processHeaderIfNeeded(document, startWith)
            .processContentIfNeeded(document, startWith)
            .processFooterIfNeeded(document, startWith);
    }

    private DocumentProcesser processContentIfNeeded(Document document, DocumentProcessStep step) 
    {
        if (step <= DocumentProcessStep.PROCESS_HEADER ) {
           // ...
        }

       return this;
    }

    private DocumentProcesser processHeaderIfNeeded(Document document, DocumentProcessStep step) 
    {
        if (step <= DocumentProcessStep.PROCESS_CONTENT ) {
           // ...
        }

       return this;
    }

    private DocumentProcesser processFooterIfNeeded(Document document, DocumentProcessStep step) 
    {
        if (step <= DocumentProcessStep.PROCESS_FOOTER) {
           // ...
        }

       return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each step can be represented as an action/command. I will use `Consumer<Document>`, but you can use your own abstraction, if it fits the scenario better. Since the order matters, use a collection like `List` to keep the required actions in order.

```
List<Consumer<Document>> actions = List.of(
        document -> processHeader(document),
        document -> processContent(document),
        document -> processFooter(document)
);
```

A processor class handling the actions:

```
public class Processor {

  private final List<Consumer<Document>> actions;

  public Processor(List<Consumer<Document>> actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
  }

  public void process(Document document, int step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++) {
      Consumer<Document> action = actions.get(i);
      action.accept(document);
      int currentStep = i + 1;
      if (currentStep == step) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It may be appropriate to make the step of each `Action` as part of the API in order to avoid working with the indexes as in this example.

```
public interface Action {
  
  void accept(Document document);
  int getStep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to control the execution based on logical input parameter in a method in Java ...
>
>
>
> ... What could be cleaner, readable and easily maintainable way to do this? ..."*

You're asking for many different re-factors.

*Logically*, you can use a *[class structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)* to distribute *document*.
And, *[methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)* to *encapsulate* the *processes*.

Here is an example.

```java
class Process {
    Document document;

    void a() {
        processHeader(document);
    }

    void b() {
        a();
        processContent(document);
    }

    void c() {
        b();
        processFooter(document);
    }
}
```

A *"cleaner, readable and easily maintainable way"*, would be to just format the code.

```java
void process(Document document, int step) {
    this.processHeader(document);
    if(step==1) return;
    this.processContent(document);
    if(step==2) return;
    this.processFooter(document);
}
```

I guess you could adjust the *[relational operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)*, although you're currently using an "early-return" design, which is actually more *logical*.

```java
void process(Document document, int step) {
    if (step > 0) this.processHeader(document);
    if (step > 1) this.processContent(document);
    if (step > 2) this.processFooter(document);
}
```

Realistically, you're looking for an *[agile design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development)*.
Keep in mind, these can be confusing, and they are not tailored for every abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear what's wrong with your code or why you don't like `switch`, for example, but if your sole question is how not to use "if-then-else", then I'd have used `switch expression`s, if you're using Java 14 or higher:

```java
public int process(Document document, int step) {
    this.processHeader(document);

    return switch (step) {
        case 1 ->  //expression #1;
        case 2 ->  //expression #2;
        case 3 ->  //expression #3;
        default -> //expression or throw
    };
}
```

If you're having Java version < 14, then go with simple `switch`, as:

```java
public int process(Document document, int step) {
    this.processHeader(document);

    switch (step) {
        case 1:  //return code #1;
        case 2:  //return code #2;
        default: //return code #3;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for the use case specified in the question - for e.g. when step=2 , both case 1 and case 2 should execute.

Comment: @user762421 this is just an example providing semantics and syntax. The rest, what the engineer will put in the blocks, depends on that very engineer.

Comment: Ok, got it. I was fine using Switch - Case but unfortunately it did not solve my use case.

Comment: Then kindly formulate clearly what you want and what is the problem. "Didn't solve my use case" is very broad and generic.

Comment: The use case is right there in the question - the code snippet is the use case. Is that not clear? just trying to understand how to put it better next time.

Comment: Also, what part of the question implies that I don’t like switch-case construct?